# Perl: Get (unresolved) path of symbolic link

Tags: perl

I have a perl script whose path is **/scripts/original/ascript.pl**

A symbolic link to this script also exists: **/scripts/linked/ascript.pl**

In ascript.pl, I need the path of where the script was called from (so either /scripts/original or /scripts/linked).

abs_path() always returns the resolved location:

```
use strict;
use Cwd qw(abs_path);

print abs_path($0); # Always prints /scripts/original/ascript.pl
```

How can I get the full unresolved path?

Comment: *"I need the path of where the script was called from"* You shouldn't need to do this. Explain why you think it's necessary.

Comment: It's a script that dynamically generates an HTML page. It can be called from different location (different URLs but even from local command prompt). Depending on from where it's called, the script needs to make subtle changes to the generated page.

Comment: Then pass a parameter to the script as  normal.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Cwd::getcwd()` to get the unresolved path to script. But this has already been implemented in a more robust and general way in [`FindBin`](https://metacpan.org/pod/FindBin), so we do not have to reinvent the wheel:

```
use FindBin;
print '$Bin: ', $FindBin::Bin, "\n";
print '$Script: ', $FindBin::Script, "\n";
```

**Output**:

```
$Bin: /scripts/linked
$Script: ascript.pl
```

You check out the source of `FindBin` [here](https://metacpan.org/source/XSAWYERX/perl-5.28.0/lib/FindBin.pm).

Comment: @Zippy1970 Strange. What system are you on? How do you run the script? If you run the script from a shell, what is the current directory of the shell when you run the script?

Comment: It's running on an old Debian system. I'm testing the script from a shell. When I do, the current directory is /scripts/linked and still it returns /scripts/original

Comment: Ok, I still think it should work. So in order to make progress in solving this issue, I think you should debug the source of the `FindBin` module. Try to download the source of `FindBin` from [here](https://fastapi.metacpan.org/source/XSAWYERX/perl-5.28.0/lib/FindBin.pm). Then put that file in e.g. a temp directory, for example `/tmp/mylib/FindBin.pm`. Then at the top of your script add `/tmp/mylib` to you Perl search path by using `use lib '/tmp/mylib'`. Now you can start debugging the module by adding debug print statements to `/tmp/mylib/FindBin.pm` and ...